# API to create interactive PDF

Tags: java, objective-c, pdf, pdf-generation

I was looking at different ways to create PDF reports for our clients report tool. I found [this link](http://uptownstudios.net/_pdf/uptownstudios-interactive.pdf) where they can perform action and forms on a PDF document. Is it possible to generate those PDF's programmatically? Like is there any API that can create such a PDF?

I have used apache POI and  iText but it don't have these capabilities. Have any one have come across any open source or commercial tools for this purpose?

My main target users will be iPad users. So having this API in objective c will also help.

Comment: refer this : http://www.raywenderlich.com/6581/how-to-create-a-pdf-with-quartz-2d-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-1

Comment: @Mayur: I guess the key word here is "interactive"

Answer (score 1):

Well if you use a Mac you can use iBooksAuthor. It´s a mixture of WYSIWYG and code. Basically it´s WYSIWYG, but you can easily add more than the in iBooksAuthor included interactivity by using HTML (and JS + CSS) iFrames. I don´t know if it produces PDF but it definitely outputs some iPad capable file cause it´s a programm by app that targets interactive textbook production for ipads and macs. This i a very easy to use (and free) solution if you are targeting mainly ipads and some macs and iphones.

Answer (score 1):

This PDF was generated with Adobe InDesign CS5.5 (v7.5.3) and bases on PDF version 1.7. Adobe put a lot effort into generating interactive PDFs. As far as I know you can embed HTML 5 content to achieve fancy-looking animations.

There is also a [Adobe InDesign Server](http://www.adobe.com/ch_de/products/indesignserver.html) (approx. USD 14'000+) that helps you to automate your publishing process.

Answer (score 1):

I am a little bit out of touch with them, but it could be that pdflib is able to add active elements.

On the other hand, there are big differences in the capability to handle smart PDF between the various PDF viewers on iDevices, and you might have to do extensive testing. Therefore, the suggestion by Ben may be the better path for iDevices as primary target.